# Order by clause is invalid in common table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Throwing and error "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified".
 When I user top 100 percent, throwing different error like one of the coloumn used many times

Comment: Can you share the entire query? Also, what [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Why not use a temporary table rather than a cte? CTE will not allow an ORDER BY

Comment: else use order by outside CTE

Comment: When I remove Order by clause it throws error "The column 'BudgetTask__c' was specified multiple times for 'ord_dupes'"

Comment: @SandeepBade Which means you have multiple problems with your query. Without showing your query, all you will get are general responses that you will likely not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query is missing the selection of data from the CTE, so we can't see all of the query right now, the error is pretty clear though. It is invalid to order a CTE since the order it outputs in can be re-ordered by the select query which is using the CTE itself.

consider:

```
    WITH foo as (
         SELECT id,name FROM bar ORDER BY id ASC
    )
    SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY name DESC
```

What is the meaning or purpose of the order within the CTE? if the query engine obeyed it, it would perform excess sort work for no purpose.

You perform ordering as your final step - ordering as an intermediate step *only* makes sense in the scenario of a TOP keyword where you want only a sub-set of data based on an order.

Answer (score 0):

What part of the error message do you not understand?  The `ORDER BY` should only be in the outermost query.

SQL tables and results sets represent *unordered* sets.  This is true of subqueries and CTEs as well.  The one exception is that the `ORDER BY` is allowed in the outermost query to order the result set.

```
WITH ord_dupes AS (   
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bas2."BudgetTask__c", bas2."BudgetResource__c"
                                ORDER BY bas2."LastModifiedDate" DESC
                               ) as rk,
             bas2.*, bas2dupes.*  -- should list out the columns
    FROM bas2 INNER JOIN 
         bas2dupes
         ON bas2."BudgetTask__c" = bas2dupes."BudgetTask__c" AND 
            bas2."BudgetResource__c" = bas2dupes."BudgetResource__c"   
     )
SELECT od.*
FROM ord_dupes od
ORDER BY ? DESC ;
```

Your `ORDER BY` column is `"BudgetTask__r.BudgetHeader__r.Project__r.ProjectNumber__c"`.  If that is the name of a column, then use it.  But, if so, I strongly recommend that you fix your data model, so you are not using periods in column names.

Otherwise, just put the correct column for `?`.